# Remove or disable NetworkManager?

Tags: linux, boot, yum, networkmanager

I installed wicd on my Fedora19. The main reason is that I could not get NetworkManager icon displayed in my tint2 system tray (I am using Openbox3.5.2). Now that I am not using NetworkManager anymore, I have 2 options : either remove it or disable it.

What I get when I try to remove :

```
# yum autoremove NetworkManager

    *[...]*
    Removing:
     NetworkManager                           x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-9.git20130709.fc19              @updates                                 3.9 M
    Removing for dependencies:
     NetworkManager-l2tp                      x86_64             0.9.8-4.fc19                              @updates                                 332 k
     NetworkManager-openconnect               x86_64             0.9.7.0-2.git20120918.fc19                @koji-override-0/$releasever             469 k
     NetworkManager-openvpn                   x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-3.fc19                          @updates                                 635 k
     NetworkManager-openvpn-gnome             x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-3.fc19                          @updates                                 236 k
     NetworkManager-pptp                      x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-3.fc19                          @updates                                 461 k
     NetworkManager-pptp-gnome                x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-3.fc19                          @updates                                 100 k
     NetworkManager-vpnc                      x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-2.fc19                          @updates                                 435 k
     NetworkManager-vpnc-gnome                x86_64             1:0.9.8.2-2.fc19                          @updates                                 116 k
     anaconda                                 x86_64             19.30.13-1.fc19                           @koji-override-1/$releasever             7.7 M
     anaconda-widgets                         x86_64             19.30.13-1.fc19                           @koji-override-1/$releasever             669 k
     anaconda-yum-plugins                     noarch             1:1.0-9.fc19                              @koji-override-0/$releasever              24 k
     avahi-autoipd                            x86_64             0.6.31-11.fc19                            @koji-override-0/$releasever              41 k
     chrony                                   x86_64             1.29-1.fc19                               @updates                                 550 k
     cryptsetup-python                        x86_64             1.6.2-1.fc19                              @updates                                  55 k
     glade-libs                               x86_64             3.15.0-1.fc19                             @koji-override-0/$releasever             1.4 M
     isomd5sum                                x86_64             1:1.0.11-1.fc19                           @updates                                  54 k
     libreport-anaconda                       x86_64             2.1.7-1.fc19                              @updates                                  10 k
     libreport-cli                            x86_64             2.1.7-1.fc19                              @updates                                  29 k
     libreswan                                x86_64             3.5-2.fc19                                @updates                                 3.1 M
     libuser-python                           x86_64             0.59-1.fc19                               @koji-override-0/$releasever              61 k
     ntpdate                                  x86_64             4.2.6p5-11.fc19                           @koji-override-0/$releasever             117 k
     openconnect                              x86_64             5.01-1.fc19                               @koji-override-0/$releasever             992 k
     openvpn                                  x86_64             2.3.2-4.fc19                              @updates                                 943 k
     pkcs11-helper                            x86_64             1.10-1.fc19                               @koji-override-0/$releasever             129 k
     pptp                                     x86_64             1.7.2-20.fc19                             @koji-override-0/$releasever             139 k
     pykickstart                              noarch             1.99.32-1.fc19                            @koji-override-0/$releasever             1.5 M
     pyparted                                 x86_64             1:3.9-3.fc19                              @koji-override-0/$releasever             667 k
     python-babel                             noarch             0.9.6-8.fc19                              @updates                                 4.2 M
     python-blivet                            noarch             0.17-1.fc19                               @koji-override-1/$releasever             2.1 M
     python-meh                               noarch             0.26-1.fc19                               @updates                                 240 k
     python-nss                               x86_64             0.14.0-1.fc19                             @koji-override-0/$releasever             810 k
     python-pwquality                         x86_64             1.2.3-1.fc19                              @updates                                  20 k
     python-pyblock                           x86_64             0.53-4.fc19                               @koji-override-0/$releasever             206 k
     pytz                                     noarch             2012d-4.fc19                              @koji-override-0/$releasever             139 k
     tigervnc-license                         noarch             1.3.0-7.fc19                              @updates                                  18 k
     tigervnc-server-minimal                  x86_64             1.3.0-7.fc19                              @updates                                 2.3 M
     trousers                                 x86_64             0.3.10-3.fc19                             @koji-override-0/$releasever             809 k
     vpnc                                     x86_64             0.5.3-18.svn457.fc19                      @updates                                 191 k
     vpnc-script                              noarch             0.5.3-18.svn457.fc19                      @updates                                  18 k
     xl2tpd                                   x86_64             1.3.1-13.fc19                             @koji-override-0/$releasever             356 k

    Transaction Summary
    ======================================================================================================================================================
    Remove  1 Package (+40 Dependent packages)

    Installed size: 36 M
    Is this ok [y/N]:
```

I think it's weird that so much packages can be removed with NetworkManager (I still have gnome3 installed alongside). What's more it wants to remove packages that seem quite important after a peak at the man :

```
chrony (programs for keeping computer clocks accurate)
anaconda (for fedora installation or somethin')
openvpn (why the heck should I remove that ?)
```

etc.

The other option is disable NetworkManager launching on startup, but how can I do it ? I looked at the /etc/rc.d directory (I think this is where a program launched at startup shoud be put) but did not see any trace of NetworkManager!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, Fedora is not Gentoo that you could tweak to the very last dependency. But did you try `remove` instead of `autoremove`, it seems many of the packages don't actually depend on NetworkManager.

Also NetworkManager is much more powerful than Wicd and its `nm-applet` creates an ordinary system tray icon that should be supported by any environment. It always worked well for me. Maybe you could try to start a bug report either with Fedora or with NetworkManager upstream.

If you want to tweak Fedora beyond basic user experience, you should learn the basics of the tools used there. Then you wouldn't search in `/etc/rc.d` but you would rather use the `systemctl` command. Note that `systemd` is a bit tricky with regard to stopping D-Bus activated services and finally you might be best with `chown -x /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 0):

For stopping and disabling NetworkManager daemon

```
service NetworkManager stop
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

To remove NetworkManager without removing dependencies, use rpm method

first list it using

```
rpm -qa | grep NetworkManager
```

then to erase the package

```
 rpm -e packagename --nodeps
```

Eg:  `rpm -qa NetworkManager-gnome-0.8.1-43.el6.x86_64 --nodeps`